# Pretty URLs with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL `http://localhost/index.php?user=1`. When I add this `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ ./index.php?user=$1
```

I will be now allowed to use `http://localhost/user/1` link. But how about `http://localhost/index.php?user=1&action=update` how can I make it into `http://localhost/user/1/update` ?

Also how can I make this url `http://localhost/user/add` ?
Thanks. Sorry I am relatively new to `.htaccess`.

Comment: The basics, http://24ways.org/2013/url-rewriting-for-the-fearful/

Comment: Are all your users identified by letters or numbers? Or both? E.g. `/user/1`, `/user/BigChris`, `/user/BigChris1`?

Comment: @BigChris numbers only

Comment: Htaccess tutorial for beginners https://helponnet.com/2021/04/15/htaccess-tutorial-for-beginers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the idea @denoise and @mogosselin. Also with @stslavik for pointing out some of the drawback of my code example.

Here's how I do it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]*)/([a-z]*)$ ./index.php?user=$1&action=$2
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]*)$ ./index.php?user&action=$1
```

by using `var_dump($_GET);` on the link `localhost/user/1234/update` I got

```
array (size=2)
  'user' => string '1234' (length=4)
  'action' => string 'update' (length=3)
```

while `localhost/user/add`

```
array (size=2)
  'user' => string '' (length=4)
  'action' => string 'update' (length=3)
```

which is my goal. I will just only do other stuffs under the hood with PHP.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to turn

`http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.php?user=1&action=update`

into

`http://www.yourwebsite.com/user/1/update`

You could use

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]*)/([a-z]*)$ ./index.php?user=$1&action=$2
```

To see the parameters in PHP:

```
<?php 
echo "user id:" . $_GET['user'];
echo "<br>action:" . $_GET['action'];
?>
```

- The parenthesis in the .htaccess are groups that you can call later.
  with $1, $2, etc.
- The first group I added ([0-9]*) means that it will
  get any numbers (1, 34, etc.).
- The second group means any characters
  (a, abc, update, etc.).

This is, in my opinion, a little bit more clean and secure than (.*) which basically mean almost anything is accepted.

Comment: Thanks, but how about the user = empty? Example `localhost/index.php?user&action=add`. How can I make it into `localhost/user/add` ?

Comment: When you do this rewrite - and perhaps the site has been live for a long time, are there things you should consider? that example.com/news/slug-of-title is the same as example.com/index.php?action=news&slug=slug-of-title ?

Answer (score 7):

a simple way is to pass only one variabe to index.php like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?data=$1 [QSA]
```

and in your index.php file you do this

```
$data = expload("/",$_GET['data']);
$user = $data[1];
$action = $data[2];
```

this one works for all cases, when you try to pass many variables, it doesn't work in case you do something like this though

```
http://localhost/user/add/12/54/54/66
```

the last variable always takes the value `add/12/54/54/66`

Comment: `expload` has a nice ring to it.

Comment: It is `explode` not `expload`

Answer (score 6):

you can write something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?user=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I'm aware this is a rather old answer. but just wanted it made aware for any that come back here, this link is long dead.

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged this with PHP, I'll add a little perspective from what I did, and it may or may not help you.

You can, of course, write solely in .htaccess, being  careful about order. For instance, let's say that you have:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/update$ ./index.php?user=$1&action=update
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ ./index.php?user=$1
```

Then it should, upon receiving

`http://localhost/user/1/update`

go to

`http://localhost/index.php?user=$1&action=update`

and not

`http://localhost/index.php?user=$1`

Now, what I did instead was push everything to `index.php?q=$1`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1
```

Then I used index.php to handle how the query was broken up. So let's say someone enters

`http://www.example.com/user/18239810/update`

this would go to

`http://www.example.com/index.php?q=user/18239810/update`

From there, explode the query string along the first `/` to give `user` and `18239810/update`.

This would tell me that I need to pass `18239810/update` to the `user` controller. In that controller, I again explode the argument into the user id and command, and I can switch on the command to tell how to load the page, passing the user id as an argument to the `update` function.

Very quick and dirty example (index.php):

```
<?php
$getString = explode('/', $_GET['q'], 1);
$controller = $getString[0].'Controller';
require_once('/controllers/'.$controller.'.php');
$loadedController = new $controller( $getString[1] );
?>
```

Of course, this means that constructors all must take a string argument that will be parsed for acceptable values. You can do this with explodes and switch statements, always defaulting back to the standard front page to prevent unauthorized access based on random guessing.

Answer (score 3):

For `/user/add` you will need to do a separate rule because you have no "middle parameter". So:

```
RewriteRule ^user/add$ ./index.php?action=add [L,QSA]
```

You can then do additional rules for URLs that contain additional parameters:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$ ./index.php?user=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This will allow you to perform actions on existing users. E.g. `/user/1/update`

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try this.

Comment: Ahhh damnit! I completely forgot the square brackets!

Answer (score 1):

Its simple just try this out !

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^game/([0-9]+)/([_-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$  index.php?user=$1&action=$2 [L,NC]
```

Thats it !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is very simple:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule index/user/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?user=$1&action=$2

RewriteRule index/user/(.*)/(.*) index.php?user=$1&action=$2
```