# Pretty url not redirecting, htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'am quite new with htaccess. I have successfully created .htaccess file with following rules to redirect user with pretty url.

**My actual url**

`http://localhost/domain.com/Job-Details.php?Job_ID=30`

**What i want to achieve**

`http://localhost/domain.com/30`

**My Current htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /domain.com/

# Get the URI-path directly from THE_REQUEST variable
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\s/(.*)\.php [NC]

# Search friendly URLs for job detail page 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ Job-Details.php?Job_ID=$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

**Issues I'am facing**

1. Redirection with pretty url not happening. I'am stil seeing old url
2. Using mentioned htaccess when i enter pretty url in address bar directly then page displays fine but url gets changed to my current url automatically.

any idea what wrong i'am doing here.

Comment: It appears there is a missing rule for the first condition. Such a rule would need to redirect the old URI to the new one. The second batch then rewrites new to old. Also, you need to remove the `R=301` from the rule in the second batch.

Comment: yes, i added RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \Job-Details.php?Job_ID=([0-9]+) [NC] above first condition & RewriteRule . Job-Details.php [L] after both mentioned conditions. then retstarting the server stopped url changing to old one. But redirection to new pretty url  is still a issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the following `/domain.com/.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /domain.com/

# Redirect actual URI to SEF URI
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (?:GET|HEAD)\s\/domain.com\/Job\-Details\.php\?Job_ID\=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

# SEF URI for Job-Details page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ Job-Details.php?Job_ID=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Change `R=302` to `R=301` if you are happy with the results. Remember to clear your cache before testing this, otherwise your browser may redirect based on historical cache.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This worked as desired & Yes, i'am a happy men once again :-)

Comment: Mike - it's working for some urls & for some not. any reason for this?

Comment: That would be a cache problem. Make sure it is completely cleared for the site so that everything works properly.

Comment: Thanks Mike, got it working by closing everything down & restarting :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:
`RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ Job-Details.php?Job_ID=$1 [NC,L,R=301]`

`RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ Job-Details.php?Job_ID=$1 [L,QSA]`

With R=301 you were creating a 301 redirection.

Comment: did changes & restarted my web server but still same issue.

Comment: try adding ```Options +FollowSymLinks``` at the beginning of the htaccess

Comment: does that fix your issue #2?

Comment: No, still the same issue. again restarted the server post adding Options +FollowSymLinks but no result.

Comment: try looking at that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080835/pretty-urls-with-htaccess

Comment: i saw this thread before posting question but didn't help me to achieve desired results.