# Allow window.location but prevent direct access to a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, apache, security, web

I have a script file named **script.php** which is accessed from another php file called **main.php** through the "**Window.location**" command. I want to prevent direct access to file, i.e, no one can type script.php in the URL bar and view the contents of the file. But I want my main.php to be able to redirect to script.php using window.location. Any way to do this?

I have tried using **Debug Backtrace** and **preg_match()** but these are also blocking the window.location from main.php. Any way to get around this?

Comment: This is impossible per definition. It would mean you publish _and_ not publish some resource at the same time. You have to decide yourself...

Comment: htaccess and pretty url may do the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080835/pretty-urls-with-htaccess

Comment: One way is, you can set a session in `main.php` and check in `script.php` that whether the session exists. You can allow access if the session exists. And don't forget to unset that session in the beginning of other pages. You can't do it otherwise.

Comment: You can check the 'referer' header in the script.php file.

Comment: A user will still be able to view using dev tools. As @arkascha mentions, anything client-side needs to be published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what and why you want to do. There is no way to only allow a script to open a URL, because the browser will handle it.

Normally you should check in the files itself, if the user is allowed to use them. So you have to find a logic for you, how to tell you script, if the user should see it. Otherwise you can do some other action, like displaying an error or redirect him back to you `main.php`.

Just some quick ideas ...

**Idea 1.)** If possible, you can `include()` the `script.php` in `main.php` and block the direct access via `.htaccess`. Then you don't need a redirect and no one can access it directly.

**Idea 2.)** Set a session variable in `main.php` like `$_SESSION["allow"] = true;` and check this again in `script.php`. Afterwards set the value to `false`, so the next call will be fail.

**Idea 3.)** Add a parameter to the file call, like `script.php?allow=true`. But in this case, all users who know the parameter could call it.

**Idea 4.)** Add a custom parameter to the redirect, wich is only valid for a given time. To be simple, something like php `time()`. Check if the parameter is within a short time limit. But in this case, the redirect url has to be generated when the `main.php` file starts the redirect. Otherwise the request could be already to old.

So that are my ideas. Hope something gives you a hint how to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I used session variables in the way you said to get around this.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to vote the answer up then. ;)