# How to remove special character is url with php and htaccses

Tags: php, html

How do I change the url from `product?p=$name` to `product/$name`.

I tied to use the `.htaccses` file but couldn't figure it out.

The link in php

```
echo"<a href = 'product?p=$name'></a>";
```

Comment: Look what i've found! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080835/pretty-urls-with-htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess rewrite for query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty URLs with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080835/pretty-urls-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

Try .HTACCESS file again. This time enter following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)/$ /product.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Note: I changed *product?* to *product.php?* because most likely you have PHP files.