# .htaccess print "pretty" urls from code

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Yes, I know, there are tons of questions like this, but I can't find one which solves my problem so at cost of receiving downvotes I'm going to ask this again. Even a duplicate link may help me.

This is a job that I've never done before, I have this kind of URL `demo.html?code=IT-ROM-FCO` where:

- `IT` is the IATA code for *"Italy"*
- `ROM` is the IATA code for *"Rome"*
- `FCO` is the IATA code for *"Aeroporto di Roma Fiumicino"*.

I have to rewrite the above URL to display like this `airports/italy/rome/aeroporto-di-roma-fiumicino`, the strings for the result are coming from an API service.

I know the simple rewrite to change `products.php?id=7` to `products/7` but I never done such task (get an URL - retrieve some data in PHP w/ the given code - "pretty" print the new url)

Comment: If you tried something that may have failed, maybe you should include it in your question.

Comment: No @Fred-ii-, I really don't know how to accomplish this task, I'm so frustrated

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080835/pretty-urls-with-htaccess --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php --- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049 - to name a few.

Comment: [*"So if I do this will search engines recognize my urls and indicize them?"* - So this goes further then, as in "SEO"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028206/htaccess-print-pretty-urls-from-code#comment75083135_44028313). I think the question's already getting too broad now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- My job is to return that kind of URL, then someone else in my office will do something with a Joomla component called sh404SEF to do "SEO things" ...I'm a programmer, SEO is a nightmare for me.

Comment: SEO questions should be asked on the [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo), tagged with [seo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo). See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/seo-in-stack-overflow

Comment: I know @Fred-ii-, but this regards a programming problem too as my script works with that codes, my boss wants that URL to be "pretty" I think it is not _strictly_ related to SEO. This is the situation I am in: the script needs that codes - boss asks to "pretty print" URL - SEO specialist will do her magic later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a job for .htaccess. `mod_rewrite` needs to do its work before PHP is even invoked.

Send the request to PHP, but then instead of rendering HTML build the "pretty" URL you want and respond with a redirect header to that URL.

If you absolutely need to do this with a rewrite, you might consider building a static map of codes -> URLs and having `mod_rewrite` consult that map.

Comment: So if I do this will search engines recognize my urls and indicize them?

Comment: If you return a redirect to a search engine spider it should recognize that as the canonical URL and index that address, yes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- OP has a need to get a request with a defined URL pattern and return both data and a differently-formatted URL. The function requestURL -> prettyURL requires an API query. I am suggesting a way to make that happen. How does that *not* help?

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it... the URL `airports/italy/rome/aeroporto-di-roma-fiumicino` doesn't exists, I can't do that! My scripts do need that codes "IT-ROM-FCO" to take data from API provder and print a result