# How to get value after / in URL

Tags: php, html, server

I am trying to get the value after the `/` in a URL in PHP.

I have tried using `$_GET['va']`, but this only works for the following,

http://localhost:8080/default`?va=xxx`

What I'm trying to get is this,

> http://localhost:8080/default`/xxx`

How do I get the `xxx` value after a `/` in PHP.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

*Edit*
Thanks to everyone who answered, I wasn't very clear in stating what I wanted. It appears what I was looking for is known as a **pretty URL** or a **clean URL**.

I solved this by following [Pedro Amaral Couto's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49654349/9285506) answer.

---

Here is what I did;

I modified my `.htaccess` file on my Apache server, and added the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ default.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ default.php?page=$1
```

Then I modified my `default.php` file to GET ['page']

```
<?php
   echo $_GET['page'];
?>
```

And it returned the value after the "/".

Comment: Try using `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: you need to parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: Actually the value in your URL would be `default/xxx` unless your real question is "how to get the content after the last slash in an URL"

Comment: Is your script already triggered when calling that second URL? Is this based on rewrite rules in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: I think you may want to look up some REST concepts and PHP routers

Comment: I don't understand why several people are mentioning $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. You can't access http://localhost:8080/default/xxx without configuring the HTTP server for that purpose. Most probably that was not done, therefore most probably the PHP script won't be run and that super-global won't be accessed.

Comment: @ddr45, what's the HTTP server you're using? Is it Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make what is called "[pretty URLs](https://www.seo-theory.com/how-do-pretty-urls-help-search-engine-optimization/)" (and [other names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL)).

You need to configure the HTTP server appropriately, otherwise you'll get a 404 error. If you're using Apache, that means you may configure .htaccess with RewriteEngine module activated. You also need to add regular expressions.

There's already a question in StackOverflow concerning that subject:

- [Pretty URLs with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080835/pretty-urls-with-htaccess)

Here are another relevant articles that may help:

- http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls
- https://medium.com/@ArthurFinkler/friendly-urls-for-static-php-files-using-htaccess-3264e7622373

You can see how it's done in Wordpress:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Where.27s_my_.htaccess_file.3F

If you follow those, you won't need to change the PHP code, you may use $_GET to retrieve "xxx".

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for: [$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, `'/index.html'`.

Comment: You can't use that if you can't use the URL without a 404 error.

Comment: Hi @PedroAmaralCouto, obrigado pelo seu comentário! May be OP is asking for `/default/xxxx/my_php_page.php` ;) You are guessing he/she is asking for pretty urls but is is not clear. I just answering the question: *"how to get value after / in URL"*

Answer (score 1):

```
basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Answer (score 1):

So the `$_GET` global variable is for parsing the query string.

What you're looking for is the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` global variable:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

`$url` will now contain the full URL of your path. You'll need to use `explode('/', $url)` to break up that full URL into an array of little strings and parse it from there.

Example:

```
$pieces = explode('/', $url);
// this will get you the first string value after / in your URL
echo $pieces[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in 2 ways.

1- do these steps

- Get URL
- Explode by `/`
- Get Last element of array

2- Add `.htaccess` and map that value for some variable

```
RewriteRule ^default/(.*) page.php?variable=$1
```

and you can get `$_GET['variable']`