# how to echo when user click on anchor tag in php?

Tags: php

I want to echo on dynamic url but when I use ? then it is working and when I use / then the url changing but nothing echo out.

```
<?php
 $pages = array("story1", "story2", "story3", "story4");

 if(isset($_GET['stroy2'])) { 
      echo "You are reading Story 2!";
 }

 if(isset($_GET['stroy3'])) {
      echo "You are reading Story 3!";
 }
 ?>

<html>
<body>
  <form action="kids.php" method="post">

    // $i=2; here and below line is not working. This is the problem.
     <a href="http://www.abcd.com/kids.php/<?php echo $pages[$i];?>" <?php echo $pages[$i];?></a>
  </form> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

The line works when I use question mark "?" after kids.php? and the content is also changing:

```
<a href="http://www.abcd.com/kids.php?<?php echo $pages[$i];?>" <?php echo $pages[$i];?></a>
```

My problem is that I want to use / instead of question mark ?

Comment: `stroy2` != `story2` apart from that you can use htaccess to rewrite the url, can you show the raw output of the url

Comment: @ Masivuye Cokile Thanks for the reply. But I dont understand your answer. stroy2 != story2?

Comment: This might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: @Sarah he means check `if(isset($_GET['...`

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for something that is called pretty URLs.

For example, if I have the page `http://localhost/index.php?user=1` and want to turn it into `http://localhost/users/1` you could add these lines to your `.htaccess` file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ ./index.php?user=$1
```

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080835/pretty-urls-with-htaccess) will most likely help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes You are right and genius. I want to know there is not a number on the end its kids.php?story1 or kids.php?story2 .... how how to achieve this. Do I need to rewrite RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ ./kids.php?story1, RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ ./kids.php?story2, RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ ./kids.php?story3 again and again.

Comment: @Sarah You should read up on regular expressions. In short, the RewriteRule above means: take whatever's inside the parenthesis `(.*)` and append it to the URL as a `user` parameter instead of the `$1`.

Comment: Look at the comment that @DanMan placed. He explains it very well. Also, please consider accepting the anwser so other people with similar problems can find a solution as well.