# Rewrite pretty URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to use htaccess to make an URL such as www.domain.com/profile.php?id=1 to www.domain.com/1/ and www.domain.com/1/contact or www.domain.com/1/gallery.

Would you like to help me?

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: @dean I searched on Google I got www.domain.com/profile.php?id=1 to www.domain.com/1/

I have files profile.php, contact.php & gallery.php.

but I don't know how to rewrite URLs like www.domain.com/1/contact

Comment: You might want to take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080835/pretty-urls-with-htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic rule to hide index.php from the URL. Put this in your root .htaccess file.

mod_rewrite must be enabled with PHP and this will work for the PHP version higher than 5.2.6.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

i get it from here 
[htaccess remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)

Comment: Why does the PHP version matter? There is no PHP in this answer