# Making pretty urls with .htaccess

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I want to make pretty URLs in this format www.example.com/countryId/stateid but I want my API end-point to route to index.php in /public folder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I keep getting 404 error and I don't know where am getting it wrong.
This is my URL "http://localhost/location/src/public/countryId/stateId" and I want the URL endpoint to route to http://localhost/location/src/public/index.php. The .htaccess file exists in public/.htaccess where index.php is

Comment: Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25081097/6411031

Comment: That will mean refactoring the whole application because at some point, the application was working

Comment: Somehow, you have to capture the pieces of the url that is being redirected; otherwise how would you show different pages?  If the application was working at some point, look to see how it was getting that information, and that will give you insight on how your htaccess needs to feed that info to index.php