# How do I change get request url?

Tags: php, html

First and foremost, I am learning html and php for the first time and I wanted to understand how to convert a get request like:

example.com?query=test to something like example.com/test/

and does the same thing. I looked all over and maybe I am searching wrong, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080835/pretty-urls-with-htaccess).

Comment: And you want to do a POST instead of a GET

Answer (score 1):

If you get that when submitting a form, change the method from get to post.

To collect the sent variable instead of using `$_GET["varName"]` use `$_POST["varName"]` or `$_REQUEST["varName"]`

For example:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Collect values:

```
$fname=$_REQUEST["fname"];
$lname=$_POST["lname"];
```