# Changing URL so post/{number} in HTML resolves post?id={number}, but still displays post/{number} as URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm struggling pretty hard with .htaccess. Even though I looked up quite a few solutions here, I couldn't get to setup the following:

I have a file called index.php. Inside the index.php I have a link like

```html
<a href="post/12345678901">Post</a>
```

Clicking the link, should lead to a file in the same directory called post.php. Inside the post.php I'm grabbing the id through $GET['id'].

But I still like to display post/12345678901 as the URL.

I already tried editing the .htaccess but clicking the links leads to a 404.

```html
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+) /post.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty URLs with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080835/pretty-urls-with-htaccess)

Comment: Disable `MultiViews`. That is necessary, when you have such an “overlap” between the fake path (`/post`) and an existing file (`/post.php`).

Comment: Please share more details - what do you mean by "I still like to display post/12345678901 as the URL"?

Comment: @NicoHaase I wanted the URL to look like "post/12345678901". Please check out Martin's solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a RewriteRule but you probably need a ReWriteCondition to go with it else this rewrite will be applied to every call to a page on the apache.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

# Edited to show root location of files. 
# also added NoCaseSensitivity flag.
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/? /post.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Also remove the first `/` in the second part of the `RewriteRule` because that will be domain.com/post.php which might not be your *actual* file location.

Your HTML appears to be showing *relative* filepathing which is not a good idea and might come back to bite you in the future, As a recommendation every URL on the same domain on your HTML should start with a `/` so;

```
<a href="/post/12345678901">Post</a>
```

Which can then be manipulated by the `.htaccess` to go where you need, even in another folder (not the base).

Comment: I added a "/" to my href and copy/pasted your code for the .htaccess, but unfortunately again 404. My .htaccess is in the same root folder as index.php and post.php. Is this right?

Comment: @arif Does it work to access `/post.php?id=<whatever>` directly?

Comment: @arif does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I'll contact my hosting provider to see if they restricted access to the .htaccess file. Seems pretty strange that changing the .htaccess file doesn't show any effect. I'll get back as soon as I get a reply!

Comment: @arif I have noted in the past that often you will need to force refresh the browser cache when reloading htaccess outputs. So try CTRL+F5 refresh on your page and see if that makes a difference. The htaccess I posted should work for you unless there's something else going on that I'm unaware of. Cheers

Comment: @arif you can test if your `.htaccess` file is being read by simply forcing an error -- write some random rubbish in the file and upload it and then try and refresh your website. If the page loads ok then your htaccess is not being read.

Comment: Seems like there was a problem with my hostin provider! Now it works, but I had to remove the # comments after !-f and !-d. Do you know why? And should I also use the "/" when linking files inside the same folder? Like "/image.png" or "image.png"?

Comment: @arif sorry, yes that's my mistake, comments needed to be on separate lines. I have updated my code. I think for best practise always link to the root (so yes, use `/`) but glad you got it sorted! Cheers