# I'm trying to write a clean url for my website using the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in php

Tags: php, url

I have two webpage link together like when a button is press it leads to the second webpage.
my problem is that I'm trying to get a clean url with the `.php` removed.
now my url looks like this

`http://localhost/ecommer%20flower%20shop/flowers/list.php`

and the second webpage

`http://localhost/ecommer%20flower%20shop/flowers/about.php`.

i want my url to be like

`http://localhost/ecommer` flower `shop/`

`http://localhost/ecommer` flower `shop/about`

the code i have written for this in *index.php*

```php
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
    # code...
    return include_once './flowers/list.php';
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/about') {
    # code...
    return include_once './flowers/about.php';
}
```

but this is not working and gives blank page, i don't know my mistake or what to do to fix code

Comment: First you'll need some rewrite rules in your webserver to direct non `.php` requests to PHP. There are lots of examples of this sort of thing online already if you search - you don't need to struggle alone. But also we probably don't need to repeat them again here.

Comment: You need to use .htaccess for it and to be specific it's called pretty URL. If you google that you should get much info on how to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080835/pretty-urls-with-htaccess

Comment: You should do a "url re write" with your hosting software, nginx or apache. Nginx https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/08/nginx-rewrite-examples/  Apache https://fedingo.com/how-to-rewrite-url-to-another-url-in-apache/

Answer (score 1):

Default setting of servers software search in directions index files (`index.html`, `index.php`). If you rebuild your catalog it can work like you want

`/flowers/index.php`  (`/flowers`)

`/flowers/about/index.php` (`/flowers/about`)

`/flowers/something/index.php`  (`flowers/something`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this.

write this in your Apache `httpd.conf` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/about$ ($1)/about.php
RewriteRule (.*)/list$ ($1)/list.php
```

Now you can request `http://localhost/flowers/list`
and Apache will send that request to the file `http://localhost/flowers/list.php`